# How would I combine these queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

So I have some code like this:

```
objects_list = A.objects.filter(some_param = some_value)

for obj in objects_list:
    object = B.objects.get(pk=obj.another_param)
    #do stuff with the B object
```

Is there any way to combine that into one query or something? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(some_param=some_value).values_list('another_param', flat=True)
b_qs = B.objects.filter(pk__in=a_qs)

for b in b_qs:
    #do stuff with b
```

Or, if you want to consolidate:

```
b_qs = B.objects.filter(pk__in=A.objects.filter(some_param=some_value).values_list('another_param', flat=True))

for b in b_qs:
    #do stuff with b
```

Comment: `__in` was what I was looking for! I knew I had done it before, but it slipped my mind. Thanks!